# Sql to find rows in table A that do not exist in table B for a specified array of identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (table A) containing a list of ids, and another table (table B) that has up to 3 rows that will match against table A using the identifier. The rows in table B also have a type column, which will be 1, 2 or 3.

I am trying to create a query that will return a list of distinct ids from table A that have at least one missing row in table B for a variable list of types.

For example, if I have the following table A

| Id |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |

and table B

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |

I am looking for a query where I can pass in:

1 - Get E

2 - Get C and D

3 - Get B and D

(1, 2) - Get C, D and E

(1, 3) - Get B, D and E

(2, 3) - Get B, C, and D

(1, 2, 3) - Get B, C, D, and E

Have been trying to use various methods of joining and using where not exists on these tables, but have so far been unable to come up with a query that does the above as expected.

Comment: CROSS JOIN A with the String_Split() result from the input, and then do a NOT EXISTS() on B for the results.

Comment: "Have been trying to use various methods of joining ..."  Where???  We don't see a single query on this post.

Answer (score 1):

The theory you are looking for is known as [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), you can do this with a `NOT EXISTS` and a `HAVING`, e.g.

```
DECLARE @Types TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT @Types (Id) VALUES(1), (2);

SELECT  a.Id
FROM    dbo.TableA AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    dbo.TableB AS b
            WHERE   b.Id = a.Id
            AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Types AS t WHERE t.Id = b.Type)
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Types)
        );
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JubPx1z8)**

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @array varchar(255) = '1,2,3';

WITH Reference AS
(
  SELECT * FROM dbo.A
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@array, ',')) AS s
)
SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM Reference AS r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.B 
  WHERE B.Type = r.value
    AND B.Id = r.Id
);
```

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AxN4vwXg)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (ID CHAR(1), Type TINYINT);
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID, Type) VALUES ('A',1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 3), ('A', 3), ('D', 1), ('E', 2), ('E', 3);

DECLARE @Types TABLE (Type TINYINT); INSERT INTO @Types (Type) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

SELECT a.ID
  FROM @TableA a
    CROSS APPLY @Types t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableB b
      ON a.ID = b.ID
      AND t.Type = b.Type
 WHERE b.ID IS NULL
 GROUP BY a.ID;
```

You'd likely be best off using a [UDTT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/using-user-defined-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) to pass in a table of values and applying it. From there it's just a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `NOT NULL` predicate in `WHERE`.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` will at best create an equivalent to `NOT EXISTS`, but depending on indexes (or lack of) it can perform worse as it isn't always optimised to a anti semi join (in SQL Server at least). Although semantically equivalent, `NOT EXISTS` should be preferred over `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to come up with a solution myself before checking the answers, and it looks like my approach is somewhat similar to Aaron's, but still, here it is.

```sql
-- sample data
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Id NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES (N'A'),(N'B'),(N'C'),(N'D'),(N'E')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Id NVARCHAR(1), Type INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
    (N'A', 1), (N'A', 2), (N'A', 3),
    (N'B', 1), (N'B', 2),
    (N'C', 1),            (N'C', 3),
    (N'D', 1),
               (N'E', 2), (N'E', 3)

-- check
DECLARE @request NVARCHAR(100) = N'1,2'

SELECT
    A.Id
FROM
    @TableA A
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@request, N',') SS
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM @TableB B WHERE B.Id = A.Id AND B.Type = SS.value
    )
GROUP BY
    A.Id
```

In either case, you're probably looking to wrap this around in a [table valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql).